# Figaro - syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I haven't used Figaro before and looking at the documentation, I can't see that I've implemented this differently to the example, but when I push to heroku, I get a syntax error with the following line:

```
password: ENV["MAILER_REGISTRATION_KEY"], ENV["MAILER_REGISTRATION_SECRET"]
```

The error is: `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>`

I don't know what to change. I don't know where to put `'=>'`.

Also, I'm not sure that I've set things up correctly in the application.yml file.

I have a single line which says:

```
MAILER_REGISTRATION_SECRET: "password"
```

I don't know whether I need to add other lines similar to the pusher example in the figaro documentation and if so, how to determine what those should be.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line isn't valid yaml or ruby:

```
password: ENV["MAILER_REGISTRATION_KEY"], ENV["MAILER_REGISTRATION_SECRET"]
```

Are you trying to do this?

```
password: "#{ENV['MAILER_REGISTRATION_KEY']},#{ENV['MAILER_REGISTRATION_SECRET']}"
```

Or maybe this?

```
password: [ENV["MAILER_REGISTRATION_KEY"], ENV["MAILER_REGISTRATION_SECRET"]]
```

Comment: Thank you Ken. The second line seems to have worked to get the heroku to push properly, although I now have an omniauth callback error when i test the registration that uses that password authentication. I'll post a separate question to try and see if someone might know how to solve that problem. Thanks very much indeed for this help.